# Gazebo/Boost 'Host not found' error

Tags: gazebo, boost, ubuntu, ubuntu-oneiric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I installed Gazebo 1.0.1 (from May 15, 2012) with all required dependencies on Ubuntu 11.10 (Oneiric, 64-bit).

I get the following error when launching gzserver:

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_implboost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::system::system_error >'
what(): Host not found (authoritative)
Aborted

The same error was reported on ArchLinux but didn't find a clear answer (https://aur.archlinux.org/packages.php?ID=20839)

I changed the environment variable GAZEBO_MASTER_URI to 'http://127.0.0.1:12345' as advised and could successfully launch gazebo but the Plugin_CgProgramManager.so file was reported missing. I then quit gazebo and try to install the ogre-plugins-cgprogrammanager package, which contains the missing plugin file, after installing the nvidia-cg-toolkit package. It failed as the only available version of ogre-plugins-cgprogrammanager (1.6.4) is older than libogre-1.7.3 that is already installed.

Since then, I tried to launch gzserver or gazebo again and I get the error mentioned above, again, whether GAZEBO_MASTER_URI is set to the default 'http://localhost:11345' or to the recommended 'http://127.0.0.1:12345'.

I have two problems:

1. The 'Host not found error' when using Boost (1.46.1)
2. The missing Plugin_CgProgramManager.so in /usr/lib/OGRE/.

There is one possible solution I haven't investigated yet: installing Gazebo from the source files posted on ArchLinux and that are more up-to-date than the Debian binary on the Gazebo website (May 18 v. May 15).

If anyone has faced the same problem, thank you for your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34556/gazebo/boost-%27host-not-found%27-error/) by [brunopop](https://answers.ros.org/users/2432/brunopop/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2012-05-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Everything was solved after updating the whole system with apt-get and installing missing packages from the PPA of Ogre as described in this other thread:

http://answers.ros.org/question/32346/how-do-i-fix-this-error-message-with-gazeboogre/

---

Originally posted by [brunopop](https://answers.ros.org/users/2432/brunopop/) with karma: 16 on 2012-05-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0